# vSphere SSO split and certificates prior to 6.0 update

Tags: ssl-certificate, vmware-vsphere, upgrade

So we currently have an embedded 5.5 environment and are looking to split the roles out to meet the recommended topology for a 6.0 upgrade.  I can see that I need to spin up new servers for the SSO role, break linked mode for a multiple vcenter environment and then repoint the various services to the new SSO server.  Nothing I can find mentions the certificates used in the process though.  We currently have internal CA signed certs deployed to the various segments of vsphere.

I am struggling to work out when to present the new certificates for SSO whilst hopping to the external SSO server.  A lot of the methods for registering the certificates for SSO require the service to be registered with vCenter but the migration route seems to need the SSO to be spun up before repointing/registering.

So - should new SSO be deployed using self signed certs and then once the repointing has occurred drop in the new certificates?  Or should the new certs be in place on the new server and assigned to SSO and then make the switch?

If anyone has recently gone through the externalising of the SSO service ahead of a migration to a Platform Services Controller I would be really grateful to hear from you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So went with the following:

1. used automation tool to generate requests and formatted them in the correct chain format on new SSO hosts
2. Installed SSO on the new host
3. Used automation tool to change the certificates
4. Repointed vcenter etc to the new SSO hosts
5. Configured domain lookup providers on SSO

I think it was just a case of getting confused over how the SSL automation tool functioned but am now happily running external SSO servers ready for PSC conversion.